# How to set custom DataGrid inactive selection color?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm wondering, is there any way to set custom `DataGrid` selection color, when `DataGrid` or window, containing `DataGrid`, becomes inactive?

E.g., here's the `DataGrid` and `ListBox`, displaying the same data. Both controls has one selected item. Initially, `DataGrid` has input focus:

[image]

Everything looks OK - selected item in `ListBox` is grayed. Then, let's move focus to the `ListBox`:

[image]

Now behavior of `DataGrid` is incorrect - selection color hasn't changed.
I know about `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` and `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey`. This XAML was placed in window's resources:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="BlueViolet"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="DarkGray"/>
```

But looks like `DataGrid` ignores the second one - `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey`, and I want `DataGrid` to behave like any other controls (`ListBox`, `ComboBox`, `ListView`).

Something similar I can achieve with triggers:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image]

But this solution is incomplete. First of all, it grays selected, but unfocused cell, even grid selection unit is `FullRow`. The second thing - trigger doesn't fires when application window loses its focus.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**.

This bug was fixed in .NET 4.5, so, it isn't actual anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, but it doesn't looks elegant.

Basic problems are:

- `DataGrid.IsFocused` is permanently `false`, because focus has
  concrete cell, not a grid itself.
- There's no way to determine in cell style, is there any focused cell
  in grid. You can only test `IsFocused` for the current cell.
- Data grid doesn't reacts on deactivation of a parent window.

The only way to determine, if data grid has a focus, is a checking of `DataGrid.CurrentCell` property. Unfortunately, it is a struct, and you can't make a trigger, that checks this property for `{x:Null}`.

To solve these problems, I need two attached properties.
First of them is intended to determine, is there any focused cell in grid. The result must be `bool`, the source is `DataGridCellInfo`, so, first of all, the converter must be written:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DataGridCellInfo), typeof(bool))]
public sealed class DataGridCellInfoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(DataGridCellInfo) || targetType != typeof(bool))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        // IsValid will be false, if there's no focused cell.
        return ((DataGridCellInfo)value).IsValid;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

The attached property:

```
    public static bool GetHasFocusedCell(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HasFocusedCellProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHasFocusedCell(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HasFocusedCellProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasFocusedCellProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "HasFocusedCell",
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(FocusedCellBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

The second attached property must be changed, when parent window of grid becomes inactve:

```
    public static bool GetIsParentWindowActive(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsParentWindowActiveProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsParentWindowActive(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsParentWindowActiveProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsParentWindowActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsParentWindowActive", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(FocusedCellBehavior), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

Now, let's bind attached properties in XAML:

```
        <!-- A converter to define, is there any focused cell in DataGrid -->
        <local:DataGridCellInfoToBooleanConverter x:Key="DataGridCellInfoToBooleanConverter"/>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              local:FocusedCellBehavior.HasFocusedCell="{Binding CurrentCell, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource DataGridCellInfoToBooleanConverter}}"
              local:FocusedCellBehavior.IsParentWindowActive="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Next, I need a cell style to set appropriate background color:

```
        <!-- A style of selected cell in DataGrid, when there's no any focused cells in DataGrid -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="InactiveSelectedCellStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

and a grid style to fire triggers, when attached properties will change their values:

```
        <!-- 
            A style of DataGrid, that defines a couple of triggers, which being fired 
            when helper attached properties will change their values 
        -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="local:FocusedCellBehavior.IsParentWindowActive" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource InactiveSelectedCellStyle}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="local:FocusedCellBehavior.HasFocusedCell" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource InactiveSelectedCellStyle}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I have achived this behaviour by using DataGrid.Resources in .Net 4.5

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"/>
```

Comment: This bug in `DataGrid` was fixed in 4.5. Now `DataGrid` behaves as any "normal" `Selector`.